# Make a 2-tuple list from a dictionary using a generator or comprehension?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, list-comprehension

From a dictionary that looks like:

```
newdict = {'1':{'label':'10232'},'2':{'label':'2420'},'3':{'label':'3530'},...}
```

How can I create the following list of tuples?

```
newlist = [(1,10232),(2,2420),(3,3530)]
```

I think my list comprehension below is incorrect:

```
[newlist(k,k['label']) for (k,v) in newdict.items()]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works:

```
newlist = [(k,v['label']) for (k,v) in newdict.items()]
```

Here's a full reproducible example:

```
>>> newdict = {'1':{'label':'10232'},'2':{'label':'2420'},'3':{'label':'3530'}}
>>> newlist = [(k,v['label']) for (k,v) in newdict.items()] 
>>> newlist 
[('1', '10232'), ('3', '3530'), ('2', '2420')]
>>>
```

If you want the tuples to be int, you just need to cast the values to int as  follows:

```
>>> newlist = [(int(k),int(v['label'])) for (k,v) in newdict.items()] 
>>> newlist
[(1, 10232), (3, 3530), (2, 2420)]
>>>
```

### Explanation

`newdict.items()` is an iterator though the list of (key,value) pairs of the dictionary. So, your first mistake was trying to access `label` in the key `k['label']` instead of accessing it in the value `v['label']`.

The second problem was that you were trying to call the list `newlist` as if it was a function `newlist(k,k['label'])`. `newlist` is just a variable, you assign the resulting list to it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call `newlist` and you can access the subdict using `v`:

```
>>> [(k, v['label']) for (k,v) in newdict.items()]
[('3', '3530'), ('2', '2420'), ('1', '10232')]
```

However dictionaries are unordered so if you plan to have it ordered by the key you have to use `sorted`:

```
>>> [(k, v['label']) for (k,v) in sorted(newdict.items())]
[('1', '10232'), ('2', '2420'), ('3', '3530')]
```

or use an `OrderedDict` instead of a normal dict as `newdict`:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> newdict = OrderedDict([('1', {'label':'10232'}), ('2',{'label':'2420'}), ('3',{'label':'3530'})])
>>> [(k, v['label']) for (k,v) in newdict.items()]
[('1', '10232'), ('2', '2420'), ('3', '3530')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> newlist = [(k,v['label']) for (k,v) in newdict.items()]
>>> newlist
[('1', '10232'), ('3', '3530'), ('2', '2420')]
```

If you want also integers, you have to add int():

```
newlist = [(int(k),int(v['label'])) for (k,v) in newdict.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
newdict = {'1':{'label':'10232'},'2':{'label':'2420'},'3':{'label':'3530'},...}

final_dict = [(a, list(b.items())[-1][-1]) for a, b in newdict.items()]
```

Output:

```
[('1', '10232'), ('3', '3530'), ('2', '2420')]
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
>>> newdict = {'1':{'label':'10232'},'2':{'label':'2420'},'3':{'label':'3530'}}
>>> [(int(k),int(v['label'])) for k,v in newdict.items()]
[(1, 10232), (2, 2420), (3, 3530)]
>>>
```